# Hacer un ovillo con [hilos], [multi-hilos] y [thread]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

Sugiero combinar tres etiquetas que vienen a significar lo mismo:

- [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos): un hilo de ejecución o hebra.
- [thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread): nombre inglés para hilo.
- [multi-hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-hilos): programación con multiples hilos.

Intenté sugerir sinónimos, pero no tengo puntuación suficiente para hacerlo en esas etiquetas.

Comment: Opino lo mismo Alvaro, cual sugieres que sea el "original" y cuales sus sinonimos?

Comment: Yo me quedaría con [tag:hilos] por estar en español, pero [tag:thread] parece ser más popular.

Comment: Y, ya de paso, sugeriría [tag:hebras] también como sinónimo

Comment: Me parece adecuado usar *hilos*, no esta demas agregar hebras, jeje. Ahora a esperar al mod

Comment: @jasilva es que *hebras* se le dice en España, si no me equivoco.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sí. Al menos así lo estudiamos en nuestra clase.

Comment: Que me corrijan, pero soy de España y nunca había oído lo de las _hebras_ y sí lo de los hilos. Buscando en Google ninguno de los dos términos es extremadamente popular, de todas formas.

Comment: Jamás he escuchado  *hebras* como sinónimo de hilos en ningún libro en español...

Comment: @dwarandae Cuando lo estudié en la Universidad de Jaén (hace ya más de 10 años, me hago mayor) recuerdo que hablábamos de hebras (así que supongo que la Universidad de Granada también). De hecho, si busco "hebras java" en Google, entre los primeros resultados me sale la UGR y las universidades Politécnica y Complutense de Madrid.

Comment: Bueno, tal parecer que esa literatura técnica de España no nos llega a Latinoamérica.

Comment: Los españoles somos raros :P

Comment: Hola, ¿quizás se podría usar etiqueta la etiqueta [tag:asincronismo] o la de [tag:asincrónico]? Creo que también habría que hacer algo con estas etiquetas, como mínimo fusionarlas. Por cierto, yo también había oido lo de `hebras`, debe de ser que los españoles somos raros, raros :-D (aunque me quedo con `thread`)   //cc:@LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Reflotada en [Unamos las etiquetas “threads” e “hilos”](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1271/83).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ya que hay dos posibilidades en español: [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos) y [hebras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hebras) creo que lo mas salomónico sería escoger el término más neutral y correcto posible que sería en inglés [threads](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/threads)

Comment: Yo usaría `thread` como etiqueta principal y los demás como sinónimos. Nunca he escuchado usar ninguno de los dos en español propuestos arriba.

Comment: @Gepser yo sí, hasta los he visto en libros y en publicaciones en internet.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza quizá `hilos` puede ser más común, pero no creo que haya un libro titulado con la palabra `hebras`.

Comment: Según wikipedia, la mejor traducción sería `hilo de ejecución`, y también está `hebra` y `subproceso`. `Hilo` como tal debe ser un apodo para el concepto completo `hilo de ejecución`. Todas me siguen pareciendo raras aunque `subproceso` no suena mal. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilo_de_ejecuci%C3%B3n

Comment: Es por eso que considero que lo mejor en esta caso es el término en inglés ya que no da lugar a malentendidos ni definiciones incorrectas

Comment: *Hebra*. Primera vez que oigo ese término...