# Unamos las etiquetas "threads" e "hilos"

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Hace unos meses se publicó por aquí la pregunta [Hacer un ovillo con [hilos], [multi-hilos] y [thread]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/493/83) en la que Alvaro Montoro pedía unificar las etiquetas:

> Sugiero combinar tres etiquetas que vienen a significar lo mismo:
>
> - [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos): un hilo de ejecución o hebra.
> - [thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread): nombre inglés para hilo.
> - [multi-hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multi-hilos): programación con multiples hilos.

Veo que [actualmente *multi-hilos* es sinónima de *hilos*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/hilos/synonyms), pero [thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread) anda desparejada.

¿Qué tal si las juntamos? Parece que hubo mayoría de gente que apostaba por usar *threads* como etiqueta estándar, pues existía el debate entre usar *hilos*, *hebras*, *hilo de ejecución*... y solamente *threads* es entendido rápidamente por todos.

Nótese que pido este sinónimo de etiquetas porque el sistema de [votación de sinónimos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) está claramente fuera de uso y las peticiones por allí tardan siglos infinitos (discusiones [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197656/209901), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459/209901)). Además, si en [threads](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/thread/synonyms) se intenta poner [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos) como sinónimo da el error:

> No se pudo proponer el sinónimo:
>
> El sinónimo invertido hilos ya se propuso en la etiqueta multi-hilos

En el sentido contrario no puedo sugerirlo, pues no tengo reputacion suficiente en [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos).

Opto por este método ante la parálisis de acción en este hilo. Nótese además que una sugerencia de sinónimos podría ser cambiada de sentido por un moderador fácilmente, para que en lugar de que A sea sinónimo de B, hacer que B lo sea de A.

Comment: La idea lleva peso, veamos que piensa la comunidad.

Comment: me sumo a la propuesta. Esperemos aproximadamente 3-4 días para que varios usuarios pueden opinar.

Comment: Si por favor, puede ser que hilos quede como principal, ya que estamos en español?

Comment: Bueno, no comenté ayer, sólo puse +1 pero creo que cae de maduro. Sólo resta ver cuál gana la apuesta: threads o hilos. ¿Les parece si lo ponemos a votación? (publico, si no están de acuerdo lo borro).

Comment: @Mariano ¡buena idea! Creo que el sitio no tiene un criterio claro a la hora de elegir nombres, por lo que abrir esta "encuesta" me parece la mejor opción.

Comment: @fedorqui - Hecho, aunque sí creo que hay un criterio claro en el sitio: en español siempre que se entienda y sea de uso común y generalizado... Sin embargo, este es uno de los casos en que no siempre "hilos" es la acepción más utilizada y creo que depende de cada país (por ejemplo, yo no usaría *hilos* jamás frente a mis pares, pero entiendo que en otros países sí).

Comment: @Mariano ah, qué bueno. No conocía ese criterio y me alegra que exista. En cuanto al tema que nos ocupa, efectivamente, a mí (en España) _threads_ es la única palabra que usaría y la que siempre vi en la universidad y la empresa.

Comment: Cuando se cierra la votación?

Comment: En mi trabajo, mis jefes son de la vieja escuela y usan la palabra **Hilos** para **thread**, cuando yo les hable de los thread no entendieron, hasta que se me ocurrió decirles hilos porque un maestro así les llamaba, a lo que voy es que los que independientemente de cual quede como respuesta tiene que haber algo que diga que son lo mismo al momento de escribir la etiqueta en el "idioma" que no haya sido seleccionado

Comment: @EzequielezzeklCanul sí, eso es automático. Al generarse un sinónimo el funcionamiento es ese: mientras escribes el nombre de una etiqueta el sistema detecta el sinónimo y te lo sugiere. Haz la prueba: coge por ejemplo la [lista de sinónimos activos](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active) y ve a redactar una pregunta; si por ejemplo escribes _expresiones-regulares_ poco a poco verás que el sistema te enseña _regex_ con un pie de párrafo diciendo _además: expresiones-regulares_.

Comment: @JuanM: ¿Cuántos votos se requieren para dar por concluída la votación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hecho. Se ha creado el sinónimo:

> [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos) (etiqueta maestra) - [thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread)

Es un empate:

> [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos): +8 -2 = 6
>   [thread](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread): +8 -4 = 4
>   Etiquetas separadas: +0 -9

Lo dejo como [hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hilos) como maestra porque está en español.

Comment: Fantástico, buen trabajo ArtEze.

Answer (score 6):

## Sí. La etiqueta principal debería ser hilos

(sólo se cuentan los +1, los -1 son irrelevantes)

Para los que no pueden ver los votos en contra, este es el resultado actual:

`+8 -2 = 6`

Comment: Los que tenemos menos de 750 puntos no podemos ver los votos negativos.

Comment: @EmanuelVe ok, es un empate por el momento.

Comment: No creo que aporte demasiado saber el resultado. Cada uno debe votar lo que considere independientemente de lo que hayan votado el resto. ¡Este es un país libre! :)

Comment: @fedorqui es por transparencia, para que aquellos usuarios que no pueden ver los votos desglosados sepan como es el resultado actual. Fijate el primer comentario en este post.

Comment: @EmanuelVe desde el momento que no se puede dar el valor en tiempo real y constantemente está desfasado, no creo que cumpla con su objetivo. Quien quiera saber el desglose siempre puede preguntarlo en el chat. Transparencia será saber el resultado final, dar el desglose constantemente es como si el día de las elecciones te van diciendo el resultado parcial: hace que el voto pase de ser meditado a ser arrastrado por los acontecimientos. Mi opinión.

Comment: @fedorqui mm.. creo que es lo contrario, pasa que se vota en contra para manipular el resultado. sabiendo que otros van mirando ese resultado antes de votar, (tal vez, a falta de un criterio propio :'( ) no seria necesario si no hubiese tanta deshonestidad y se cumpliesen las reglas del post *al pie de la letra*. Te doy la derecha que es dificil de mantener, lo mejor seria un feature para hacer este tipo de encuestas mas transparentes

Comment: @EmanuelVe estoy de acuerdo en que estas encuestas deberían tener algún formato más configurable y ágil, en el que también se pudiera definir claramente el tiempo durante el que se realizará la consulta. No siempre el formato pregunta-respuestas es el más práctico...

Comment: ¿De dónde sale lo de que "sólo cuentan los +1, los -1 son irrelevantes"? Es la primera vez que lo veo (lo cual podría ser irrelevante) y me parece que complica las cosas en lugar de simplificarlas en particular porque no todos pueden ver el detalle de los votos.

Comment: @Rubén Fue utilizado en algunas votaciones. No permite que algunos usuarios lo visualicen (y no creo que sea absolutamente necesario que todos lo vean), pero es la mejor forma de garantizar que haya 1 solo voto por usuario. De esta forma, un usuario no está votando 2 veces si vota +1 a [propuesta A] y -1 a [propuesta B].

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, pero lo de "garantiza que haya sólo un voto por usuario" es muy debatible en un espacio abierto a cualquiera como SOes, por ejemplo ¿qué hay del caso de votar positivamente a dos propuestas?, ya sé no tiene "sentido evidente", pero así somos los seres humanos, hacemos muchas cosas "sin sentido".

Comment: @Rubén ese caso creo que no es un problema. Votar por dos opciones no hace que tu voto valga más que el de otra persona (cómo sí podría valer un +1 junto a un -1)

Answer (score 5):

## Sí. La etiqueta principal debería ser threads

(sólo se cuentan los +1, los -1 son irrelevantes)

Para los que no pueden ver los votos en contra, este es el resultado actual:

`+6 -4 = 2`

Comment: No puedo votar, pero va un +1 de comentario de mi parte ;-)

Comment: Un sitio de preguntas en español con una etiqueta en inglés cuando tiene una traducción a nuestro idioma ampliamente usada me parece ilógico.

Comment: @dwarandae toda opinión es respetable, sin embargo otros entendemos que es un concepto técnico cuyo nombre propio _establecido_ es `thread`. Y que un hilo es lo que mi abuelita guarda en su caja de costura XD.

Comment: @EmanuelVe No me hubiera dado cuenta, parece que va ganando.

Answer (score -8):

## No. Deberían quedar como etiquetas independientes.

(sólo se cuentan los +1, los -1 son irrelevantes)

```
+0 -9 = -9
```

- Si se vota esta opción, comentar debajo los motivos, justificando casos de uso independientes.

Comment: Falta un voto -1