# Hagamos [editing] sinónimo de [ediciones]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, meta

Hay una serie de etiquetas que se sugieren por defecto en cualquier sitio Meta. Stack Overflow en español Meta no es excepción y tenemos cosas como [editing](/questions/tagged/editing), [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) y un largo etcétera.

Dado que con el tiempo vamos utilizando conceptos en español, lo interesante es que etiquetemos con nombres en este idioma y, además, creemos sinónimos de las ya existentes en inglés, para que no se sugieran a la hora de crear nuevas preguntas. Podríamos reetiquetar todas las preguntas que las usan, pero no sería suficiente: en seguirían siendo recomendadas por el editor. Esto se debatió en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1553/83 y parece que estamos de acuerdo.

Por ello, sugiero que se cree el siguiente sinónimo:

- [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) que sea sinónimo de [ediciones](/questions/tagged/ediciones)

A la vez que sugiero al resto de gente que sugiera otras creaciones de sinónimos en otras preguntas, tal y como veo que está pasando durante el día de hoy :)

Comment: ... un feriado para limpiar un poco el hogar

Comment: @Mariano jajaja eso pensé cuando vi la cantidad de limpieza que habéis sugerido hoy: Mariano, Rubén y sstan están con el pañuelo en la cabeza dejándolo todo limpio :D

Comment: Y dejé por otros compromisos, que sino seguía... tengo una lista con 15 pendientes para proponer en Meta... quizás mañana le doy un poco más... Luiggi va a estar feliz cuando se encuentre con esto el lunes!!!

Comment: @Mariano veo a Luiggi diciendo "no puedo dejar sola a esta gente  un fin de semana: mira cómo me han dejado el sitio" :D Yo tenía alguna sugerencia de sinónimo más (de la respuesta que enlacé), e iba a meterlos en esta misma pregunta. Pero creo que es mejor uno por pregunta, por si la gente no está de acuerdo con alguna de las sugerencias. Por cierto, [la de \[threads\] e \[hilos\]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1271/83) quedó en el aire, ¿sabes si se resolvió algo?

Comment: jajaja pensé lo mismo... Tampoco estaría mal armar una ⬅️➡️⬅️➡️ *Blown Out Fatality... FINISH HIM*! y sugerir todos los sinónimos en 1 sola para este caso (-vamos, ¿quién va a estar en contra de esto?).... con [la de \[threads\]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1271/127) nunca me animé a hacer nada por lo parejo de los votos.

Comment: Ya no hay preguntas con la etiqueta [meta-tag:editing] ni con la etiqueta [meta-tag:formatting]

Comment: Qué bien, @Rubén, ¡muchas gracias! Sería bueno crear el sinónimo igualmente, pues la etiqueta sigue sugiriéndose a la hora de crear una pregunta. Supongo que [se] tiene unas cuantas etiquetas por defecto "hardcodeadas" para todos los sitios Meta

Comment: En [sinónimos de etiqueta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) aparece ediciones <-- editing y formato <-- formatting. Yo esperaba que ya no se mostrara editing ni formatting ni el las preguntas ni en las sugerencias de etiquetas, así aque asumí que algo no está funcionando bien, y considerando que eran muy pocas las preguntas que tenían esas etiquetas y que en general las preguntas proponiendo sinónimos ha sido bien recibidas, decidí ser "bold", tal vez luego investigue mas a fondo que está pasando.

Comment: @Rubén ¡lo encontré! [Add a selection of default tags to all metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63019/209901) incluye _editing_, _formatting_ y demás.

Comment: Me emocioné cuando leí "any objection", peeeero al ver que es del 2010, se me pasó XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta semana, el jueves 18 de Mayo del 2017, he aprobado tu sugerencia, ahora son sinónimos.

> [ediciones](/questions/tagged/ediciones) (etiqueta maestra) - [editing](/questions/tagged/editing)

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias.